# JDBC: How to handle IS NULL in WHERE clause for different databases?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a Java programm which connects to all kinds of databases over JDBC.
The programm is used to get data from all kinds of databases which supports JDBC.
My question is: How do I handle queries whith `NULL` in the `WHERE` clause? 
For example: The user sends me a query like

```
Select * from test where col1 = somevariable
```

variable can be `NULL`. I am working with `PreparedStatement`, using `setNull` in case of somevariable is `null`. But the `=` is not changed to `IS`.
My question is now: Does every database understand `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`? My idea is simple to replace the `=` with `IS`.
Are there any other solutions?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_col IS NULL OR some_col = 'val';` select all rows where `some_col` is `NULL` or `val`.

Comment: `PreparedStatement.set***` methods like `setNull()` can only set parameters, but they can't (and should never) modify the query. Thus, you must specify/build your query yourself. `setNull()` can be used if you have to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a certain field with a `NULL`. `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` are parts of SQL and are full safe to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do

```
... where (col1 is null and :x1 is null) or col1 = :x1
```

Depending on the context `:x1` (HQL) might be `?` (PreparedStatement), and the actual parameter repeated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [coalesce](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=coalesce) keyword. It should be supported by every / most of the databases. like This:

```
Select * 
from test 
where col1 = coalesce(somevariable,null,col1)
```